# http client connection pool for keepalive

Tags: go

I know that we can have keepalive connections in go http client by reading from the connection till the data is completely read.
The question is: how do I reuse it? Is it possible to implement a connection pool such that for different url's I can keep a keepalive connection and reuse it later in some part of the code?

Is the reuse part a function of the http client object or is it part of transport or something else if i write my own method? Is it sufficient to create a map of url[*http.Client] or something else?

Comment: Just use the same `*http.Client` for all your requests.

Comment: Connection pooling is built into the default [http.Transport](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport). No special code is required to use it.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the same http.Client is capable of holding keepalive connections across multiple url's since the http.Transport supports it? Thats awesome!